# Need help using a custom tcblistings environment for src blocks

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-babel, code

I'm trying to advise the function `org-latex-src-block--listings` to use a tcblistings environment that I like. In LaTeX the environment is used like...

```
\begin{code}[title=TITLE, language=LANGUAGE, file={ICON \ \raisebox{0.1\height}{FILE}}]
<code here>
\end{code}
```

So far I have done...

```
(cl-defun my/org-latex-src-block--listings
    (&key src-block info lang caption caption-above-p label num-start retain-labels attributes float &allow-other-keys)
  "Transcode a SRC-BLOCK element from Org to LaTeX, using listings.
LANG, CAPTION, CAPTION-ABOVE-P, LABEL, NUM-START, RETAIN-LABELS, ATTRIBUTES
and FLOAT are extracted from SRC-BLOCK and INFO in `org-latex-src-block'."
  (let ((lst-lang
         (or (cadr (assq (intern lang)
                         (plist-get info :latex-listings-langs)))
             lang))
        (caption-str
         (when caption
           (let ((main (org-export-get-caption src-block))
                 (secondary (org-export-get-caption src-block t)))
             (if (not secondary)
                 (format "{%s}" (org-export-data main info))
               (format "{[%s]%s}"
                       (org-export-data secondary info)
                       (org-export-data main info))))))
        (lst-opt (plist-get info :latex-listings-options)))
    (concat
     (format
      "\\begin{code}[%s]\n%s\\end{code}"
      ;; Options.
      (concat
       (org-latex--make-option-string
        (append
         lst-opt
         (cond
          ((and (not float) (plist-member attributes :float)) nil)
          ((string= "multicolumn" float) '(("float" "*")))
          ((and float (not (assoc "float" lst-opt)))
           `(("float" ,(plist-get info :latex-default-figure-position)))))
         (unless (plist-get info :latex-listings-src-omit-language)
           `(("language" ,lst-lang)))
         (when label
           `(("label" ,(org-latex--label src-block info))))
         (when caption-str
           `(("title" ,caption-str)))
       (let ((local-options (plist-get attributes :options)))
         (and local-options (concat "," local-options))))
      ;; Source code.
      (let* ((code-info (org-export-unravel-code src-block))
             (max-width
              (apply 'max
                     (mapcar 'string-width
                             (org-split-string (car code-info) "\n")))))
        (org-export-format-code
         (car code-info)
         (lambda (loc _num ref)
           (concat
            loc
            (when ref
              ;; Ensure references are flushed to the right,
              ;; separated with 6 spaces from the widest line of
              ;; code
              (concat (make-string (+ (- max-width (length loc)) 6) ?\s)
                      (format "(%s)" ref)))))
         nil (and retain-labels (cdr code-info))))))))
(advice-add 'org-latex-src-block--listings :override #'my/org-latex-src-block--listings)
```

The last part involves the `file` portion of the tcblisting. I'd like to use the file in the `:tangle` header argument as the `FILE` argument, and I'd like to add an icon based on the language. Below is an example table of the icons I'd like transcoded into the ICON portion of the tcblisting:

| language | icon |
| --- | --- |
| latex | \LateX |
| python | \faPython |
| bash, shell | \faLinux |
| js | \faJs |
| css | \faCss3 |
| R | \faRProject |
| sql, sqlite | \faDatabase |
| markdown | \faMarkdown |
| ELSE | \faFileCode |

How can I accomplish this?